# How to pass two different ids of different models from a controller to a view

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, mysqli

I am having an issue with passing two ids in blog posts. The first id
 displays a single post and the second one counts the number of posts.
 Each works well separately but on integrating the two, it selects a
 wrong post.

This is my code for the first model that fetches the comments

```
class News_model extends CI_Model {    
     function get_comment($id)
     {
         $this->db->select('comments.*,users.username');
         $this->db->from('comments');
         $this->db->join('users','users.id = comments.user_id', 'left');
         $this->db->where('post_id',$id);
         $this->db->order_by('date_added','asc');
         $query = $this->db->get();
         return $query->result_array();
     }
}
```

This is the model that fetches the posts

```
class News_model extends CI_Model {  
  function get_one_news($news_id)
     {
        $this->db->select('*, news.id as id');
         $this->db->from('news');
         $this->db->join('users' , 'users.id = news.user_id');
         $this->db->where('news.id' , $news_id);
         $query = $this->db->get();
         return $query->first_row('array');
     } 
  function latestnews()     {
        $this->db->select("
        news.*,users.*,comments.*,COUNT(comments.post_id) AS num_comments");
         $this->db->from('news');
         $this->db->join('users' , 'users.id = news.user_id'); 
         $this->db->join('comments' , 'comments.post_id = news.id');
         $this->db->group_by('comments.post_id');
         $this->db->order_by('news.date_added','desc');     
         $this->db->limit(4);
         $query = $this->db->get();
         return $query->result_array(); 
    }
 }
```

And here is my controller

```
function view($id)
     {       
        $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_one_news($id);
        $data["latest_news"] = $this->news_model->latestnews();         
        $data['comments'] = $this->m_comment->get_comment($id);    

        $data['content'] = 'single'; // template part
        $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);
     }
```

And finally the view file

```
<div id="sidebar" class="col-md-3 fix-left">
                <!---- Start Widget ---->
                <div class="widget wid-vid">
                    <div class="heading">
                        <h4>Latest News</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">

                        <div class="tab-content">

                            <div id="most" class="tab-pane fade in active">


                                <div class="post wrap-vid">
                                <?php if(count($latest_news)) { 
                             foreach($latest_news as $l_news){ ?>
                                    <div class="zoom-container">
                                        <div class="zoom-caption">
                                        <a href="<?php echo base_url()?bulletins/view/<?php echo $l_news['id']?>"></a>
                                        </div>
                                    <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/'.$l_news['image'])?>"
 style="height:80px;width:100px;"/>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                    <h5 class="vid-name"><a href="<?php echo  base_url('bulletins/view/'.$l_news['id'])?>"><?php echo 
 substr(strip_tags($l_news['title']), 0, 15).'..';?></a></h5>
                                            <div class="info">  
                                            <h6>By <a href="#"><?php echo $l_news['username']?></a></h6>
                                            <span><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><?php echo date( 'F jS, Y' , strtotime($l_news['date_added']))?></span>
                                             <span><i class="fa fa-comment-o">/i><?php echo
 $l_news['num_comments'];?></span>                                          
                                            &nbsp;
                                            </div>
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </div>
                                        <?php }}?>

                                </div>

                                </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: I will appreciate any assistance

Comment: So you want to display count of comments in each post..?

Comment: the count is working properly for all post but my problem is that when I click on any post, it takes me to a different post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below mentioned solution. You have error in your `select cause`. When you want data from multiple table in CI and if `columnName` is same than CI query builder will overwrite value of that column. In this case you need to give `alias` to `columnName`. Please check below.

```
$this->db->select('news.id as newsId,users.id as userId,news.*,users.*,comments.*, COUNT(comments.post_id) as num_comments');
```

And in your view file you need to change below code.

Find `$l_news['id']` and replace with `$l_news['newsId']`

This will resolve your issue. Let me know if it not works for you.

Comment: Thanks buddy.This worked like a charm.you saved my night!